# Parse lambda event json to object using python

Tags: json, python-3.x, aws-lambda

in the event of lambda i am  getting new and old images for any update in dynamo db .now in my new image  have one property names as sourceDetails which can vary eg.(please note the  string mentioned below is json

```
{'M': {'bucketName': {'S': 'postote-offers-bucket'}}}
```

or it be like for eg.

```
 {'M': {'streamName': {'S': 'someStream'},{'limit': {'N': 10}}}
```

How can i parse this result in best possible way

Comment: What do you mean by parse? What do you want to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have a new and old image coming from dynamo db change in the associated lambda event .like newImage=json.loads(json.dumps(event['Records'][0]['dynamodb']['NewImage']))  .this gives me new image of event modify .now if i have to get  bucket_name=newImage['InputSourceDetails']['M']['bucketName']['S'] i have to do something like this .Is there a better way to achieve the same .

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`jmespath`](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py) library. It's already present in the python environment of Lambda, because it's a dependency of boto3.

```py
path = 'Records[0].dynamodb.NewImage.InputSourceDetails.M.bucketName.S'
bucket_name = jmespath.search(path, event)
```

If there is no value under the path, the `jmespath.search` function will return `None`.

Btw you don't have to do the `json.loads` + `json.dumps` (as mentioned in the comment below the question), `event` is already a python dictionary.